# connectionFactory in jms component from messageListenerContainerFactoryRef

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

Can I use only **messageListenerContainerFactoryRef** in jms component url and set **connectionFactory** in **MessageListenerContainer** created by my factory class for consuming messages?

Or its an worng assumption to start with?

Comment: what is `messageListenerContainerFactoryRef` exactly?

Comment: `messageListenerContainerFactoryRef` is an attribute of apache camel JMS component.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can do it that way.